# Why am I getting an System.InvalidOperationException when I assign "SelectedIndex = 0" to a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I've got a problem that keeps my app crashing and I can't figure out why.

My code is like this:

```vb
Private Sub SelectedFieldFK_TextChanged() Handles SelectedFieldFK.TextChanged
  RefreshSelections()
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshSelections()
  If Selections Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Selections.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, New Binding With {.XPath = "..."})
  m_SelectionSorter.Refresh()
  If Selections.HasItems Then Selections.SelectedIndex = 0 '*)
End Sub
```

I'm skipping down a ListBox using the arrow keys. Via binding the "SelectedFieldFK" keeps changing its value, and the DataGrid named "Selections" keeps getting updated. After that, the first row of the DataGrid is selected. This works for the first occurence when 2 selections are to be shown. Then I continue pressing the down arrow and eventually land on an item that has one selection. As soon as the function "RefreshSelctions()" ends, the app crashes with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can only change SelectedItems collection in multiple selection modes. Use SelectedItem in single select modes.

and StackTrace

```vb
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
at System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, Object item)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdateSelectedItems(InternalSelectedItemsStorage toAdd, InternalSelectedItemsStorage toRemove)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdateSelectedItems()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(ItemInfo info, Boolean assumeInItemsCollection)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeSingleSelection(ListBoxItem listItem)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeKeyboardSelection(ListBoxItem item)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(DependencyObject newFocus, IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.FocusItem(ItemInfo info, ItemNavigateArgs itemNavigateArgs)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.FocusItem(ItemInfo info, ItemNavigateArgs itemNavigateArgs)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.NavigateByLineInternal(Object startingItem, FocusNavigationDirection direction, FrameworkElement startingElement, ItemNavigateArgs itemNavigateArgs, Boolean shouldFocus, FrameworkElement& container)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.NavigateByLine(ItemInfo startingInfo, FrameworkElement startingElement, FocusNavigationDirection direction, ItemNavigateArgs itemNavigateArgs)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.NavigateByLine(FocusNavigationDirection direction, ItemNavigateArgs itemNavigateArgs)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnKeyDownThunk(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at DatenfKatCreator.Application.Main() in C:\Users\Christoph\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DatenfKatCreator\DatenfKatCreator\obj\x86\Debug\Resource\XAML\Application.g.vb:Zeile 66.
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

When I comment line `*)` out, it works, but of course the first entry is not selected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property SelectionMode to Extended on your grid

```
 grid.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
```

However this should be the default, so check if your code (or XAML) changes it to Single

Comment: 1) But I don't want to enable multiple selections. Why should I set it to a behaviour I do not want?
2) I've tried it out, it doesn't work.
3) From the stacktrace you can see the error comes from the ListBox, not the DataGrid. And indeed, setting the ListBox's selection mode to "Extended" or "Multiple" helps - but I want single selection. What now?

Comment: Well if you don't want MultipleSelections then the error message suggests to use a different property `SelectedItem`

Comment: Let me be clear about the steps: 1) I use the keyboard to change the selection of a ListBox. 2) The code sets the SelectedIndex property for a DataGrid. 3) The error occurs as the ListBox's selection is updated (automatically because I used the arrow key, not by me).

However, do not perform the SelectedIndex-update on the totally unrelated DataGrid, and the ListBox selection update is performing just fine. In other words: why does updating a DataGrid.SelectedIndex cause the keyboard-induced SelectedItem-update of a ListBox to fail?!

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that this must be a bug in the PresentationFramework.dll: In ListBox.MakeKeyboardSelection(ListBoxItem item) they use a different code branch for SelectionMode.Single. However the callstack shows that even following this branch, you end up in Primitives.Selector.UpdateSelectedItems, which adds items to an ObservableCollection. This collection is observed by the Selector via OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged, which throws an error if SelectionMode.Single is active. I don't know why not updating DataGrid.SelectedIndex helps, but it's most certainly a nasty bug.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you, I am not an expert in WPF and your question seemed easy, instead, it is much more complex than it seemed.

Comment: No problem, any help is appreciated. I also thought this was easy to fix until I looked closer into the stacktrace, noticing that the error comes from the ListBox and not the DataGrid. Now that I've looked into the source code of the PresentationFramework.dll with ILSpy, I found this is a bug. I could solve it with a workaround, which is (after I updated the SelectedIndex): `ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended`, `ListBox.SelectedItems.Clear`, `ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single`. Since this works it's quite obviously a bug anywhere in the native code.